# How do I format code from the web using Vim?

Tags: vim

For example, to render:

```
while (head == tail) { head++; a[head] = 0 }
```

into

```
while (head == tail)
{
    head++;
    a[head] = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
:setfiletype sh|%s/{/{^M/g|%s/}/^M}/g|%s/;/;^M/g|normal ggVG=
```

Breakdown:
set the file type so that vim knows what syntax it's using ( shell script in this case ):

```
:setfiletype sh
```

insert newlines after '{' characters and before '}' characters ( type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> enter key to get a literal newline character):

```
:%s/{/{^M/g
:%s/}/^M}/g
```

insert newline after ';' characters:

```
:%s/;/;^M/g
```

same as typing ggVG= in normal mode:
'gg' =  goto top, 'V' = select lines visually, 'G' goto bottom, '=' = auto format:

```
:normal ggVG=
```

This is very simple minded and will fail in a lot of cases e.g. if there's a ';' in a string literal.
But it should get the code more readable.

Comment: This isn't shell code, and while it (sortof) works for this code, it may not work for more extensive chunks of code.  Also, instead of inserting literal control-m's in the command line, you can use "\r".

Answer (score 0):

You could install [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and get it do the work for you.  In vim you can then select a block of code and do:

```
:'<,'>!astyle
```

(where the '<,'> was added for you when you press colon.)

This will replace your selected text with the beautified version from astyle.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Windows or Linux?  I'll assume Linux since it is a vim question, even tho' vim is available for Windows.

The `indent` program is probably already installed on your Linux box, so no additional installed are needed.  Similar to ngm's answer, you can use

```
:'<,'>!indent -
```

or

```
!Gindent -
```

to pretty-ify a block of code or all the code from the current spot to the end of the file.  Be sure to include the '-' at the end of that command

See the man page for indent `man indent` for the voluminous amount of formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Use [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) to automatically integrate external formatters (e.g. clang-format and astyle for c-like languages) and run them with one button press.